# Ethernet interfaces keep changing priority, preventing connections

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ethernet

My workplace has a server running Ubuntu 20.04 and it has both a LAN and WAN connection, each connected with a separate ethernet cable. We are having a problem where the machine will randomly lose its WAN connection, causing our remote connections to hang and timeout and preventing any new connections. We are able to fix this temporarily by logging into another machine on the same LAN, then connecting to the Ubuntu server via ssh through the LAN interface and running the command "ifmetric eno1 50". This command was discovered by a past member of our team who has left, but from my understanding this is changing the priority of the WAN connection, which somehow restores connectivity to the internet. So I believe that the problem is caused by something changing the priority of the connections so that the LAN connection supercedes the WAN and prevents connections from the internet. Is there anyway I can permanently fix this or investigate further to find the cause?

(edit) Here are the output of the commands requested:

```
$ ip -br link
lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> 
eno1             UP             ac:1f:6b:a1:bd:4c <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
eno2             UP             ac:1f:6b:a1:bd:4d <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
virbr0           DOWN           52:54:00:95:94:95 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
virbr0-nic       DOWN           52:54:00:95:94:95 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST>

$ ip -4 -br address
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 
eno1             UP             X.X.X.8/24 
eno2             UP             192.168.0.20/24 
virbr0           DOWN           192.168.122.1/24

$ ip route
default via X.X.X.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp metric 200 
default via 192.168.0.239 dev eno2 proto static metric 20100 
X.X.X.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src X.X.X.8 metric 200 
X.X.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eno2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.20 metric 100 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown  

$ ip -4 neigh
X.X.X.15 dev eno1 lladdr d8:5e:d3:01:92:c5 STALE
X.X.X.16 dev eno1 lladdr 90:09:d0:09:2f:bd STALE
192.168.0.24 dev eno2 lladdr 00:11:32:f7:e0:f1 REACHABLE
X.X.X.20 dev eno1 lladdr 90:09:d0:0a:58:f1 STALE
X.X.X.21 dev eno1 lladdr b4:b0:24:1b:47:96 STALE
192.168.0.3 dev eno2 lladdr b4:96:91:53:d2:4a STALE
X.X.X.X dev eno1 lladdr 40:6c:8f:0b:0d:9d STALE
192.168.0.239 dev eno2 lladdr 80:cc:9c:82:e7:ae REACHABLE
X.X.X.33 dev eno1 lladdr b4:96:91:53:d2:48 STALE
X.X.X.1 dev eno1 lladdr 3c:08:f6:21:a5:c0 REACHABLE
192.168.0.10 dev eno2  INCOMPLETE
192.168.0.15 dev eno2 lladdr 90:09:d0:09:2a:55 REACHABLE
X.X.X.9 dev eno1 lladdr 3c:52:82:58:4e:31 STALE
X.X.X.10 dev eno1 lladdr f4:02:70:9d:99:ec STALE
X.X.X.X dev virbr0  FAILED
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't configure two default routes? Only the interface to Internet should have a default route. You should provide the current network state with these commands: `ip -br link; ip -4 -br address; ip route; ip -4 neigh` (assuming it's about IPv4).

Comment: It looks like there may be two default routes. I edited my question with the output of those 4 commands.

Comment: You'll probably have to remove the gateway configuration that uses eno2 but I wouldn't know why it was there in the first place (ask your network team if you really have multiple ways to reach Internet), nor why it would interfere (because apparently it wouldn't). It could even be the opposite depending on your specific configuration. I'm just leaving this comment because without knowing why, it's difficult to guess what should be done. Also usually one should obfuscate public IP addresses (eg: use values from 192.0.2.0/24 instead)